# What is the exact formula Mathematica uses for Riemann zeta function?

Tags: special-functions

I'm trying to find the formula of the zeta function used to plot this graph:
[image]

This is taken from Wikipedia [Riemann Zeta Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function). It was created in Mathematica by `Slonzor` in 2008.

This is his Mathematica code (added under the image in Wikipedia):

```
Show[Plot[{Re[Zeta[1/2+I x]], Im[Zeta[1/2+I x]]}, {x,-30, 30},AxesLabel->{"x"} , PlotStyle->{Red, Blue}, Ticks->{Table[4x-28,{x,0,14}]}, ImageSize->{800,600}], Graphics[Text[Style[\[DoubleStruckCapitalR][\[Zeta][ I x + "1/2"]],14,Red ,Background ->White],{-22,2.6} ]], Graphics[Text[Style[\[GothicCapitalI][\[Zeta][ I x + "1/2"]],14,Blue ,Background ->White],{-14,2.6} ]]]
```

He is using Mathematica's built in function `zeta`:

`Show[Plot[{Re[Zeta[1/2+I x]], Im[Zeta[1/2+I x]]}, ... ]]]`

[Wolfram Documentation for this function](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Zeta.html) states:

> Mathematical function, suitable for both symbolic and numerical manipulation.

Wolfram documentation lists two zeta functions:

> Zeta[s]
>
> gives the Riemann zeta function TemplateBox[{s}, Zeta].

> Zeta[s,a]
>
> gives the generalized Riemann zeta function TemplateBox[{s, a}, Zeta2].

I assume that "generalized Riemann zeta function" is "Hurwitz zeta function". [This MathWorld page](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HurwitzZetaFunction.html) has information about zeta functions used in Mathematica. Is it possible to infer from this information the exact formula used by Mathematica to draw this plot?

I'm interested to know because I'll try to plot it in Python, if possible.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! The third bullet point in [`Zeta`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Zeta.html) tells you the definition. Note that `Zeta[s]` is equivalent to `Zeta[s, 1]`, so `Zeta[1/2 + I x]` is the same as `Sum[(k + 1)^(-(1/2 + I x)), {k, 0, ∞}]`, or in LaTeX: $$\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } (k+1)^{-\left(1/2+i x\right)}$$

Comment: I'm sorry the question is closed due to "it is easily found in the documentation." But the problem is, as far as I understand, this zeta as stated in the documentation must be analytically continued to be valid in the whole complex plane. So, I'm guessing that Mathematica is using this analytically continued function to make computations for `s<1`. It would have been nice to know that function. But, thanks for your comment anyway.

Comment: In your question, you have asked about a very specific case of $s=1/2+ix$, no mention of the whole complex plane and analytic continuation. Hence, your question _is_ easily found in the documentation :) In any case, the analytic continuation is given by the eq. (3) in the [MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HurwitzZetaFunction.html).

Comment: As noted [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html#21479): "`Zeta` and related functions use Euler–Maclaurin summation and functional equations. Near the critical strip they also use the Riemann–Siegel formula."

Comment: @J.M.'seventualburnout Thanks, this was helpful.